# Разделение на файлы

Tags: c++

Как можно разделить данный код на файлы? (.h, .cpp)
Когда использовал классы, в .h находился сам класс, то есть class Name{... А в .cpp была его реализация. А как похожее разделение сделать здесь, если такое вообще возможно?

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Functor.h"

template<class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2>
ForwardIterator1 search_end(ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1, ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator2 last2){
    if (first2 == last2) return last1;  

    ForwardIterator1 ret = last1;

    for (; first1 != last1;  ++first1) {
        ForwardIterator1 it1 = first1;
        ForwardIterator2 it2 = first2;
        while (*it1 == *it2) {    
            ++it1;
            ++it2;
            if (it2 == last2) {
                ret = first1;
                break;
            }
            if (it1 == last1) return ret;
        }       
    }
    return ret;
}

class Functor{
 public:
             bool operator()(int i, int j) {
                     return i == j;
              }
};

template<class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2, class Predicate>
ForwardIterator1 search_end_if(ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1, ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator2 last2, Predicate Functor){
   
    ForwardIterator1 ret = last1;

    for (; first1 != last1; ++first1) {
        ForwardIterator1 it1 = first1;
        ForwardIterator2 it2 = first2;

        while (Functor(*it1, *it2)) {
            ++it1;
            ++it2;
            if (it2 == last2) {
                ret = first1;
                break;
            }
            if (it1 == last1) return ret;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

          
int main() {

    int* c;
    int a[10] = { 1, 26, 33, 40, 0, 1, 26, 83, 41, 50 };
    int b[3] = { 1, 26 };
  
    c =  search_end(a, a + 10, b, b + 2);

    if (c == a + 10) std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "Found on position number " << (c - a) << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"_________________________________________________________________________" << std::endl;
   
    int* n;
    int x[12] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4 };
    int y[3] = { 2, 4, 4 };

    search_end_if(x, x + 12, y, y + 3, functor());
    functor f;
    n = search_end_if(x, x + 12, y, y + 3, f);
   
    if (n == x + 12) std::cout << "\nNot found" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "\nFound on position number " << (n - x) << std::endl;
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Шаблоны помещаются в отдельный заголовочный файл. разделить код и декларацию обычно не выходит, т.к. откуда тогда компилятор будет знать какой тип нужно подставлять в исходном коде с реализацией методов?

Comment: @ Yakov Спасибо